# Python multiprocessing using a While loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand why the second function does not get called, are you not able to use While loop with multiprocessing? If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated!

```
import multiprocessing
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool

def func_ONE(data):
    while True:
        print 'Func ONE'
        print str(data)
        time.sleep(10)

def func_TWO(data):
    while True:
        print 'Func TWO'
        print str(data)
        time.sleep(10)

def worker(params):
    param1, param2 = params
    if param1:
        func_ONE(param1)
    if param2:
        func_TWO(param2)

data1 = 'bob'
data2 = 'joe'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = zip([data1], [data2])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(worker, params)
```

Comment: It maybe easier (at least for me) to use `multiprocessing.Queue()` that is shared by `multiprocessing.Process` instances (workers) than `Pool`.  But this depends on what you want. Why do you have to have func_TWO after func_ONE? If `func_ONE` has `while True` without `break`, func_TWO will never be called. That's nothing to do with multiprocessing. Do you want to use multiple CPU cores to process func_ONE and func_TWO at the same time instead of sequentially?

Comment: I want to be able to run func_ONE and func_TWO at the same time (with both of them looping) with args that are passed through the worker function. Hope that makes sense! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing, Queue, time

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, work_queue):
        # base class initialization
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

        # job management stuff
        self.work_queue = work_queue
        self.kill_received = False

    def run(self):

        while not self.kill_received:

            # get a task
            try:
                n_job, data = self.work_queue.get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty:
                break

            # the actual processing
            print "Starting %d ..." % n_job
            print str(data)
            time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    data1 = 'bob'
    data2 = 'joe'

    work_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for n, data in enumerate([data1, data2]):
        work_queue.put( (n, data) )

    num_processes = 2
    for i in range(num_processes):
        worker = Worker(work_queue)
        worker.start()
```

I guess what you want to do is something like this.

Comment: When I run this, the while loop does not keep looping? The program stops? I need it to keep looping forever. Also, how would I call a different function? In this example, you only have 1 function (run), but in my example I have two different functions. How could I call both functions and run them at the same time, and both of them have their own while loops. Hope that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: I see! That's the design. Then you probably need two worker classes with different `def run()`. And `while True` instead of `while not self.kill_received`.

Comment: Is there any way to call a function by the work_queue? For example, work_queue 1, use this function, then work_queue 2, use this function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your two functions to run in parallel, you need to have them running from different calls to `worker` rather than the same one.

Without modifying your child-process code at all, you could do that just by structuring `params` differently in the main process code:

```
params = [(data1, None), (None, data2)]
```

But I'm not sure that's actually the best way to do things. If it never makes sense to have multiple non-falsey values in the 2-tuples that are passed as arguments to `worker` with `map`, `map`, maybe `map` is not the right thing to use. You can instead use `apply_asyc` to call different functions in different worker processes, if you want:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results1 = pool.apply_async(func_ONE, (data1,))
    results2 = pool.apply_async(func_TWO, (data2,))
```

Now, your workers never return, so calling `results1.wait()` will block the main process forever, which may not be ideal (but that's a larger design issue).